# Android Vertical Scroll Bar

Tags: android, android-scrollview

In my android application i need to show scroll view like up and down arrow with scroll bar in my text and list views. If the text extends only that scroll bar should be visible. Here my sample scroll bar [image]

Is it possible to do like this. can any one help me?...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17017477/646806