# hide soft input when listview scroll

Tags: android, android-listview, android-input-method

The xml is as follow.

[image]

I want to implement the function like this: when I click the edittext, the soft input show.
when I scroll(not scroll to `OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE` state) the listview the soft input hide.

I use the  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` .

Comment: try using :android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

Comment: Use adjustPan the titlebar will be out of the screen @krunal patel

Comment: write this code on the scroll event of the listview:     InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Detect your scroll using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017477/609782),
it implements `onScrollListener`, which you will set to your `ListView` and in its `onScrollStateChanged()` you will put this code in your -

```
setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        if (scrollState !=0){
           InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
           getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);     
           inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(‌​), 0);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I kept getting errors with this. Then I restarted Android Studio and reopened my project and all worked well. Android Studio can be buggy that way.

Comment: requires API 23+

Answer (score 1):

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) 
           getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);     
           inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(‌​), 0);
```

gives a bug in AS...
Use this instead inside onScrollStateChange

```
InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(absListView.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
```