# Hide Search Bar when ListView is rolled up and view when it is rolled down android

Tags: android, listview, search, jquery-animate, material-design

I am working on a search which has a listview And at the bottom and I want that list View To hide when the scrolled up and view again when scrolled down and it would be good if it is animated and as I am using the same layout for multiple activities. I would prefer to make changes in the XML file. pl refer the screen shot [screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyZTF.png)

Comment: This might help https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer basically answers that question. Haven't tested it but logically it works. In the `/* do something */` area for the `listView.setOnDetectScrollListener(new OnDetectScrollListener()` just change the visibility of the search layout.

The link to the forum is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20540839/7295341).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it would be comfortable if there is any default way to do that hiding and view that search

Comment: Changing the Visibility will not look good on the app is there any other way to  perform a simple animation @BrendanOswego

Comment: @qwertygamer so for animating from the screen -> off screen

Comment: I want animation to Move up and hide while pulled down and move down while pulled down @ BrendanOswego

Comment: I added a new comment, easier to do it that way with adding code segments for me at least.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and let u know @ BrendanOswego

Answer (score 0):

@qwertgamer so for the animation you need a few things,

1. A XML file in an `anim` Folder inside your `res` Folder and call the file something like `search_animation.xml`.
2. Mess around with this code a bit but this is the general concept of what you want to do with it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="-100%" android:duration="600"/>
</set>
```

3. For the scrolling events you need to create an Animation by doing something like this

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.animation);
        anim.setInterpolator((new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()));
        anim.setFillAfter(true);
        YOUR_SEARCH_FRAME.setAnimation(anim);
        anim.start();
```

Comment: ALSO, have another animation.xml file that animated from off the screen -> to the screen and basically switch the values of the 'android:fromYDelta' and 'android:toYDelta' values

Comment: I tried what u gave me the hiding part worked perfectly but the animation got messed up. It's supposed to animate from its layout to the hide inside the Activity bar but it starts from the middle of the listView and ends at its own layout. @BrendanOswego

Comment: Thanks... For the Help, i resolved the issue With the Default animation search.animate().translationY(search.getHeight());