# Hide fab button with ListView when scrolling down

Tags: android, listview, floating-action-button

How can I hide fab button when scrolling listView?

I'm using this code at the moment, but it hides **FAB** button whenever I'm touching screen and scrolling, I need it to hide **FAB** button when scrolling down and when scrolling a bit up it has to be shown again

current code:

```
mListView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            if(scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL){
                floatingActionButton.hide();
            }else{
                floatingActionButton.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17017477/8089770  try this

Answer (score 1):

try this you should use `onScroll` instead of `onScrollStateChanged`

```
listview.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {


    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        // add here your logic like this
        // int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
        if (firstVisibleItem < 2) {

            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }else {
            floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: where do you use int lastItem?

Comment: its a logic part my friend you can ignore that line

Comment: I think it's better use `hide` and `show`. I did this: `if (lastItem == totalItemCount) floatingActionButton.hide();` to hide the button at the end of the scroll.