# Android Update ListView on scrolling down

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, onscrolllistener

I want ot update my listView when I scroll down I do this :

```
mConnectionList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if( mConnectionList.getLastVisiblePosition() == connectionList.size()-1 ){
                        getConnections();
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    isCrollingDown.set(false);
                    break;
                default:
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But it does not work corretlly it update when I scroll down and update when I scroll up

Also I try do this but it doesn not work coretly too :

```
        mConnectionList.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {



            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

//                Log.e("a0","a " + mConnectionList.getLastVisiblePosition());
//                if(mConnectionList.getLastVisiblePosition() == connectionList.size()-1 ){
                    getConnections();
                }


            }
        });
```

Comment: `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_DOWN` means the fingers pressing and lifting from the screen not from scrolling

Comment: You should set onScrollListener for that.

Comment: @tompok what happens when you are using setOnScrollListener is your onScrollStateChanged being executed or not?

Comment: @BrijeshJoshi yes is being execute

Comment: Try to put getConnections() method in onScroll method and put some logs over there and check if it onScroll method and your method is being executed or not ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this method for scroll down listview and select the last row so it will 
 scroll into view.**

```
 private void scrollListBottom() {
        myListView.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                listView.setSelection(listAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            }
        });
    }

myListView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() 
  @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     v.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
     return false;
}
```

});

Comment: But I don't want to scroll down list , I want to notice when user scroll down

Answer (score 0):

you shuld try like this.

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {                  
        if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
            Log.e("SCROLL", "Scroll DOWN"+scrollY);
        }
        if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
            Log.e("SCROLL", "Scroll UP"+scrollY);
        }
        if (scrollY == 0) {
            Log.e("SCROLL", "TOP SCROLL"+scrollY);
        }
        if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
            Log.e("SCROLL", "BOTTOM SCROLL"+scrollY);
        }
    }
});
```

using this you can detect your scrolling direction and then update your list 
hope this will help you.

Comment: But I have listView not scrollView

Comment: you can put your listview inside scroll view.

Comment: you can see here solution of your problem -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791100/detect-scroll-up-scroll-down-in-listview.

Comment: so what i should ot do ?